# Amazon CloudWatch: How to find ARN of CloudWatch Log group

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch

I configure Custom Access Logging for Amazon API Gateway and I need to specify CloudWatch Group name, but when I put these just name of log group in format like "API-Gateway-Execution-Logs_3j5w5m7kv9/stage-name" I get such error:

> Invalid ARN specified in the request. ARNs must start with 'arn:':
>   API-Gateway-Execution-Logs_3j5w5m7kv9/stage-name

When I open page of this log group in CloudWatch I just see the same name there and don't see ARN value. How can I find it?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Go to Cloudwatch logs, find your log group, open it and you'll see a list of log streams. There is settings icon on top right:
[image]

Click it and you'll see an option to show stream arn:

[image]

Save the settings and you'll see stream arns. The part before semicolon looks like Log Group arn

Comment: Just a note, you need only the ARN part *before* `:log-stream:<stream_id>`.

Answer (score 6):

The **CloudWatch Group ARN** format is `arn:aws:logs:{region}:{account-id}:log-group:API-Gateway-Execution-Logs_{rest-api-id}/{stage-name}`, cf. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-logging.html

Answer (score 4):

**2022 Update**

### Select your log group:

[image]

### Click `Log Group Details`:

[image]

### Copy the ARN:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
arn:aws:logs:region:account-id:log-group:log_group_name
```

See [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/iam-access-control-overview-cwl.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use AWS CLI

`aws logs describe-log-groups |  grep <log_group_name> | awk '/arn/'`

Answer (score 1):

Or you could do a `aws logs describe-log-groups | grep <name_of_group>`

That works too.